# Map integration not working

Tags: google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha application when i try to show map, its not working, i have googled lots nothing helps me. Here my code,

```
  var mapapnel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                          id: 'mapapnel',
                          fullscreen: true,
                          layout:'fit',
                          items: [{
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    height:'100px',
                                    html:'<div><script>function initialize(){ 
                                          var mapProp = {
                                               center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),zoom:5,  
                                               mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
                                                        };
                                        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);  
                                               }
                                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, \'load\', initialize);  
                                                                                            </script></div>'
                                   }]});
```

Whats wrong with my code, What change required to show the map?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Sencha Touch maps example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/example/maps)? I'm assuming that's what you're after.

If I had to guess why your code is "not working", I would guess it's because you try to inline a SCRIPT tag with code directly into the child panel.